# create custom application facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

How I can create a custom page like this http://www.facebook.com/AmyPorterfield/app_208412272531040 on facebook?
I'll use it to connect to my timeline page inside the favorite, appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to developers.facebook.com and register an application there.
You will have to create your application in some dev package (visual studio). You will have to host it also. Then point the application in facebook to your application on your server.

Hope this helps

Comment: Wesley, you explained how to create a application canvas page, which is not what the question is wanting ... the link that the poster included points to a application page, NOT an application canvas page which is what you described.